# Graphics in Android Emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator

I have installed Android Studio 2.3.2 with Android Emulator(API 24).
The graphics in emulator seems very much unclear. The text is not clear as well.
[image]

[image]

I have already gone through other answers which suggests to change the emulated performance setting for graphics. But the problem is that, I am not able to edit the Graphics or Resolution as it is disabled. I had already closed emulator before changing any options but still all options are disabled except AVD Name. 
[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't change emulated performance of AVD in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44328225/cant-change-emulated-performance-of-avd-in-android-studio)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

1. Install the latest updates in Android Studio.
2. Disable the Device Frame by edit action.

   [image: avd edit]
3. Start the emulator and Go to Extended Control

   [image: extended]
4. Go to Settings and change OpenGLES render to **Desktop native OpenGL**

   [image]
5. Restart Emulator and Resize the Emulator Window.

   [image]