# Google Maps Emulator

Tags: android, google-maps, android-emulator

I'm having issue with Android Studio and getting Google maps to work on my emulator.

I've set up an emulator with Play installed on it. The map activity is viewable but the map itself does not render and just the google logo appears in the bottom corner of the screen.

The error given is: Google Maps Android API v2 only supports devices with OpenGL ES 2.0 and above

Apparently this is because I need to use hardware to boost the graphics performance in the AVD setup. However this is not available to me on any emulator that has Play installed.

So I can can essentially only have one or the other.

Any advice on how to solve this would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Go into an emulator, and find advanced settings. In there, you'll find the Graphics setting under emulated performance:

[image]

If you can't see GLES 2 on either option, your system does not support it or you don't have the latest driver. Alternatively, system settings could make the system prefer e.g. a non-dedicated graphics card over a dedicated graphics card,
 making it run on a potentially unupdated GPU. Make sure the system prefers the dedicated graphics card, assuming you have one.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30695568/6296561) is a related issue on the topic of GLES version.

Comment: I can't do this as the option for changing Graphics settings is greyed out.

Comment: @Nowandthen98 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44328225/cant-change-emulated-performance-of-avd-in-android-studio

Comment: This doesn't solve it for me as I need a Play enabled device to run Google Maps

Comment: Then you're stuck. If you can't change the version used, and your computer for whatever reason defaults to GLES 1(.1) you can't fix it.