# Can't change "Emulated Performance: Graphics" setting in android studio

Tags: android-studio

I'm trying to create a virtual device in AVD, however the graphics setting is grayed out. I've been able to successfully install HAXM and have also disabled windows Hyper-V. But the option is still grayed out.

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't change emulated performance of AVD in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44328225/cant-change-emulated-performance-of-avd-in-android-studio)

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue and the answers here didn't work. Try this:

`vim ~/.android/avd/Pixel_3a_API_28.avd/config.ini`

Search for `hw.gpu.mode = software` change it to: `hw.gpu.mode = host`

Now it shows correctly in AVD manager as:

[image]

You have other options too: https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-acceleration?authuser=1

Answer (score 1):

I don't know exactly why but sometimes images with the Google Play Store don't allow you to configure graphics. Try with another image.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to edit the emulator ini file directly - under ~/.android/avd-emulator-name/config.ini
U will see the options:
hw.gpu.enabled=yes
hw.gpu.mode=software (or hardware)

Change as needed