# The Android Studio emulator is not working on Windows 7

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-emulator-plugin

The Android Studio emulator is not working. When I force the AVD manager to load, it shows the error.

The error screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Try Genymotion emulator https://www.genymotion.com/

Comment: I tried, but I show the white blank screen only.

Comment: then try to test in direct device, instead of wasting time, functionality anyway it will work

Comment: Update your GPU drivers, the error says that the amd vulkan drivers are not found

Answer (score 10):

Select *Software - GLES 2.0* in the Emulated Performance while creating the AVD (or edit the existing AVD):

[image]

Comment: This eventually worked for me, but I had to enable my Graphics option first.  This answer allowed me to change it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58376934/137670