# Andriod emulator closed because of an internal error

Tags: flutter, internals

I install flutter and andriod studio, when i create a virtual device and when i run it, it sends me this error

[click here for error snap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/byyPI.png)

i tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58391908/android-studio-emulator-is-not-working-on-windows-7) solution but it doesn't work.

**update:**

i download this folder [download folder image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7lSig.png) form the link you provided

extract the folder, now what should i do next.

[folder snap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WvQ54.png)

i added the amdvlk64.dll file in the emulator folder but it keep sending same error when i run the emulator

[emulator folder snap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/njEEe.png)

please help where if anyone know the solution

Answer (score 0):

I've had this error once... What I did was deleting my current made emulator and creating a new one. For some reason it worked for me and I didn't get this error anymore.

As for the dll files, if they are still missing then try this website
https://www.dll-files.com/download.dll.html and look for the dll files that are missing.

Comment: i also did that, deleted previous and made the new one, but still same error, i open the link and download the folder which u provide can u help with that , when i extract the folder it shows 2 file, i edit my question with folder snap

Comment: Okay, you have the dll fiilles downloaded, right? What you need to do is find your Android Studio root folder. Once you are there rename the dll file as the one missing and paste it in your emulator's folder.

AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/emulator/lib64/gles_swiftshader

You have to paste it there and it should work propperly.

Comment: but i only get the download.dll and readme text file from folder, should i paste the download.dll file to my emulator's folder? i edit my question too which folder i download, please check that.

Comment: First name download.dll as amdvlk64.dll and then paste it in the emulator folder

Let me know if it works

Comment: i edit my question, please check , it send same error.

Comment: If that doesn't work, then I've no more ways to solve it, man. Sorry... Let's hope somone answers