# Can't select an option for "Emulated Performance: Graphics" while creating new AVD

Tags: android, android-studio, avd-manager

Please has anyone else encountered this issue previously? I have tried creating a different hardware profile, also tried downloading a different API level still no luck. Here's the screenshot:

[image: Issue screenshot]

Comment: check the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44328225/cant-change-emulated-performance-of-avd-in-android-studio). the same question was asked there.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't change emulated performance of AVD in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44328225/cant-change-emulated-performance-of-avd-in-android-studio)