# AVD screen is like broken. Can anybody say what it looks like?

Tags: android

When I start AVD, screen looks like it is broken. Can anybody help with this?

Android Studio is running on W10 Laptop.
I tried to Wipe Data, reconfigure AVD, reinstall Android Studio, nothing help. Another interesting thing is this appear when I start directly on Laptop, screen appear as in the picture, but when I'm connected using RDP, this issue doesn't appear. Later, if I want to work from Laptop, then is OK, even if I restart Application or Activity.
[Print screen of my screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bpd2o.png)

[AVD properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ltl6M.png)

Comment: That looks like a AVD graphics issue, see [Can't change emulated performance of AVD in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44328225/295004). You should edit your post to include which OS and if you are using a dock at work vs home.

Comment: Hi, both Desktop and Laptop has W10, without dock. I tried recommendation from article, but nothing help.